# Extracting data of two overlapping rasters

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, extract, raster

I am trying extract the data of two overlapping set of rasters (one, a stack of 35 rasters, all from the same source and the second an elevation raster) to get a data.frame of the values (mean of the values) of each pixel of all the rasters.

The description of the raster stack is the following:

```
> stack_pacifico
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 997, 709, 706873, 35  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -81.62083, -75.7125, 0.3458336, 8.654167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : F101992.v//ts.avg_vis, F101993.v//ts.avg_vis, F101994.v//ts.avg_vis, F121994.v//ts.avg_vis, F121995.v//ts.avg_vis, F121996.v//ts.avg_vis, F121997.v//ts.avg_vis, F121998.v//ts.avg_vis, F121999.v//ts.avg_vis, F141997.v//ts.avg_vis, F141998.v//ts.avg_vis, F141999.v//ts.avg_vis, F142000.v//ts.avg_vis, F142001.v//ts.avg_vis, F142002.v//ts.avg_vis, ... 
min values  :                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0,                     0, ... 
max values  :                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63,                    63, ...
```

And for the elevation raster:

```
> elevation_pacifico
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 997, 709, 706873  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -81.62083, -75.7125, 0.3458336, 8.654167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : COL_msk_alt 
values      : -16, 5164  (min, max)
```

It is my first time with raster data and I want to extract the data by grids of 1km2 (or less). I know the resolution of both rasters can be coerced to fit into that area requirement, also both dimensions are equal, so the number of pixels per raster is the same.

My question is, can I only merge all the rasters (the ones in the stack and the elevation raster) and extract the data with the confidence that all the pixels overlap (or are in the same place)? Or do I have to create a master SpatialGrid or SpatialPixel object and then extract the raster data to these objects?

Thanks in advance,

Data from the raster stack can be downloaded by clicking at this link (if you want to download all the stack, you can use the script in https://github.com/ivanhigueram/nightlights):

http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/v4composites/

Elevation:

```
#Download country map and filter by pacific states
colombia_departments <- getData("GADM", download=T, country="CO", level=1)
pacific_littoral <- c(11, 13, 21, 30)
pacific_littoral_map <- colombia_departments[colombia_departments@data$ID_1 %in% pacific_littoral, ]

#Download elevation data and filter it for pacific states
elevation <- getData("alt", co="COL")
elevation_pacifico <- crop(elevation, pacific_littoral_map)
elevation_pacifico <- setExtent(elevation_pacifico, rasters_extent)
```

Comment: If the resolutions, extents and coordinate systems of the two stacks are identical, then the cells will overlap perfectly. The rows of `stack_pacifico[]` will correspond to the same cells as do the elements of `elevation_pacifico[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jbaums. I have another doubt. It is clear how to extract the raster data using `raster::extract` and a SpatialPolygon object, like a shape file from cities or countries, but how can I extract the data for each of the pixels of the raster. Should I covert the raster to a SpatialPolygon, Pixels or Points object and then `extract` the data using these objects as `y`?

Comment: If you want the data for all cells, then any of the following: `as.data.frame(r)`; `r[]`; `values(r)`, `extract(r, seq_len(ncell(r)))`, where `r` is the `Raster*` object, either `stack_pacifico` or `elevation_pacifico`. For a stack, that will give you a `data.frame`, with a column per layer and a row per cell, and for a single raster layer it'll give you a vector.

Comment: Well, that worked really well, I only add the `data.frame` option into the `extract` function: `extract(r, seq_len(ncell(r)), df=T)` that gives me a `data.frame` with an ID variable per pixel (or grid). 

I still want to be certain about the identification of pixels in all the rasters. It is there a way to get the lan-long of the pixels? I am thinking in trying `rasterToPoints` function, but I am also aware that this process can lead to wrong or missed data. 

Any ideas? 

(Thank for your extensive help!)

Comment: For the coords of all cells: `coordinates(r)`. For particular cells, `xyFromCell(r, 1:10)`.

Comment: Right now I have a list fill with TRUE values. Thank you so much! There is a way to mark your answer as the best? In the future may be someone will have the same doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the resolutions, extents and coordinate systems of the two raster objects are identical, then the cells will overlap perfectly. You can confirm this by looking at the coordinates:

```
coordinates(stack_pacifico)
coordinates(elevation_pacifico)
# are they the same?
identical(coordinates(stack_pacifico), coordinates(elevation_pacifico))
```

You can extract all cell values for each object using one of the following:

```
as.data.frame(r)
values(r)
r[]
extract(r, seq_len(ncell(r)))
```

where `r` is your raster object.

(These do not all have consistent behaviour for single raster layers - `as.data.frame(r)` ensures the result is a `data.frame`, which would have a single column if `r` is a single raster layer; in contrast the alternatives would return a simple vector if used with a single raster layer.)

The rows of `as.data.frame(stack_pacifico)` correspond to cells at the same coordinates as do the rows of `as.data.frame(elevation_pacifico) (or, equivalently, the elements of`values(elevation_pacifico)`).

Answer (score 2):

Or do this:

```
s <- stack(elevation_pacifico, stack_pacifico)
d <- values(s)
```